# syntax error from CREATE USER with variables giving username and password

Tags: mysql

Stored procedure code:

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root` @`localhost` PROCEDURE `P_CreateUser3` (
  IN _Username NVARCHAR(30), IN _Password NVARCHAR(32), IN _DBName VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
  CREATE USER _Username @'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY _Password ;
  GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT 
  ON    _DBName.* 
  TO    _Username @'localhost' 
  WITH GRANT OPTION ;
END $$
```

> Error Code: 1064
>    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL  server version for the right syntax to use near '_Password ;
>     GRANT
>       SELECT,
>       UPDATE,
>       DELETE,
>       INSERT 
>     ON
>       `pr' at line 6

help me please.

Comment: The unsupported use of stored procedure input parameters as passwords in a `CREATE USER` or `GRANT` statement is [documented in this bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28406).

Comment: Hmm I wouldn't have even tried that. Just reached straight for exec('SomeQuery')

Comment: @eggyal Looks like I had it as an answer originally. I restored and undeleted it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL CREATE USER with a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951570/mysql-create-user-with-a-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the use of stored procedure input parameters as passwords in a `CREATE USER` or `GRANT` statement is [documented in this bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28406) as *unsupported*.  So you cannot actually do what you attempted.

It would be possible to `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` a statement which is built by `CONCAT()` to concatenate in the new password, but this is *not a secure method* and is therefore not recommended. You lose all the security benefits of the stored procedure if you were to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You must use prepared statements because the variables doesn't evaluate directly in queries.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `create_user`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `create_user`(
    `user_name` VARCHAR(50), 
    `passwd` VARCHAR(255),
    `ip` VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
   set @sql = concat("CREATE USER '",`user_name`,"'@'",`ip`,"' IDENTIFIED BY '",`passwd`,"'");
   PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
   EXECUTE stmt1;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

   set @sql = concat("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO '",`user_name`,"'@'",`ip`,"' ");
   PREPARE stmt2 FROM @sql;
   EXECUTE stmt2;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;

   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```