# MySQL CREATE USER with a variable?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to do this:

```
#Variables
SET @username="jdoe", @password="secret";

# Insert a new MySQL User
CREATE USER @username@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY @password;GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO @username@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY @password WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 120 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 60 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 60 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 2;
```

But get:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@username@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY @password' at line 2
```

How do I use a variable in the CREATE USER statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [syntax error from CREATE USER with variables giving username and password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368966/syntax-error-from-create-user-with-variables-giving-username-and-password)

Comment: @aleroot I'm not sure that's the same issue since it concerns creating a stored procedure.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `dynamic SQL` as:

```
SET @query1 = CONCAT('
        CREATE USER "',@username,'"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY "',@password,'" '
        );
PREPARE stmt FROM @query1; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SET @query1 = CONCAT('
    GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO "',@username,'"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY "',@password,'" WITH
          MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 120 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 60 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 60 
          MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 2'
        );
PREPARE stmt FROM @query1; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working... I get `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'secret;
    GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO jdoe@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY secret
     ' at line 1 `