# How to create a new user for MySQL with Java?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I want to create a new user for a MySQL database from NetBeans but I don't know the core code for it.

I've tried:

```java
try {

    String query = "CREATE USER = '?' @'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY = '?'; ";

    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, pwd);
    PreparedStatement pstmnt = con.prepareStatement(query);

    pstmnt.setString(1, newUser[0]);
    pstmnt.setString(2, newUser[3]);

    pstmnt.execute();
    pstmnt.close();

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: 
Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

I know in MySQL you can create a new user using:

```sql
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? Based on this, your prepared statement syntax is wrong: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Comment: do you want to create a new table in mysql using netbeans?

Comment: Have you at least tried this code? What is the output?

Comment: @AluanHaddad, I thought I'd use similar code

Comment: @geunhter Yes, I have

Comment: why don't you try to call a stored proc instead of a normal query.

Comment: @reds example, pls

Comment: @reds you implying stored procedure??

Comment: wait i'm just trying to make some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TimSolo [How To have Dynamic SQL in MySQL Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure) states that After 5.0.13, in stored procedures, you can use

```
dynamic sql
```

Omesh [MySQL CREATE USER with a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951570/mysql-create-user-with-a-variable) uses dynamic SQL to create a new user and grant privileges

my concoction uses

```
stored procedures + dynamic sql
```

to produce the following answer for creating a new user:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`(IN username VARCHAR(250), IN pwd VARCHAR (100))
BEGIN

SET @s = CONCAT('CREATE USER "',username,'"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY "',pwd,'"');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```