# How to format a MySql CREATE USER statement for Golang

Tags: mysql, go

I am trying to create a MySql user from a Golang program but I am unable to find the correct formatting of the SQL string:

```
    _, err := db.Query("CREATE USER ?@`%` IDENTIFIED BY ?",username)
```

I have tried many variations: enclosing the `?` in backticks, single quotes, parenthesis, but nothing works.

I either get
`sql: expected 0 arguments, got 1` (or 2 if I add one or two parameters), or I get

```
Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?@`%` IDENTIFIED BY ?' at line 1
```

I have found similar questions but none is using the CREATE USER, and none of the solutions found there worked for me.
Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368966/syntax-error-from-create-user-with-variables-giving-username-and-password and https://stackoverflow.com/a/11951620/965900

Comment: Thank you @mkopriva but neither of those is a Go problem. I was having a problem with using the placeholders in Go. But thanks anyway.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken both of them point to a bug in **mysql** which causes the placeholders not work for the `CREATE USER` command. Go or not go, the problem is in mysql, at least that's how I understood it. And if you think Go does the placeholder replacement and not mysql I would think twice.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround:

```
    password := "aaargh!"
    s := "CREATE USER '" + username + "'@`%` IDENTIFIED BY '" + password + "'"
```

This is working in my test.

Comment: What is wrong @Volker? Could you pls explain? It does work in my program.

Comment: @Benedetto the problem with building sql statements with string concatenation is that you're simply exposing yourself to sql injection.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks a lot. I am aware of this issue. I am only building an internal automation that will not be exposed externally and will not receive uncontrolled input. Besides I am a beginner with Go so I am just doing my best, but I would not use unsanitized SQL if this was coming from an external source such as a form or similar.